# What is the full mechanism for oxidation of toluene to benzoic acid using permanganate?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have managed to get some of the way (I think):

I am particularly interested in the **full** mechanism i.e. all the curly arrows that take you from toluene right through to benzoic acid.
[image]

Comment: The answer to that question does not address the full, step-by-step mechanism.

Comment: I'm not sure if such a "full" mechanism exists. If it does, it's almost certainly radical, not some combination of pericyclic reactions.